# Why do I have both eth0 and "Wired connection 1" in my 'Network Connections' list?

Tags: networking, network-manager, indicator, ethernet

Why do I have both eth0 and "Wired connection 1" in my 'Network Connections' list? Don't they both refer to the same device eth0?

This list is accessible by clicking 'Edit Connections...' from the menu you get by clicking on the network icon in the upper panel area.

ifconfig shows I only have eth0, wlan0 and lo

Answer (score 1):

One are connection profiles of NetworkManager, the other are actual interfaces/devices.

You can configure a multitude of profiles, adding, modifying, deleting them. Then you tell NetworkManager to "activate" the connection on a device. That means, to configure the actual networking interface.

Check
  `nmcli connection`
vs.
  `nmcli device`